# Obtaining a joint density function from a given function by scaling

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus, density-function

> **Question:** Given $f(x,y)=e^{-\lambda(x+y)}$ for $x,y\geq0$ and $\lambda>0$, what constant must $f(x,y)$ be multiplied by to get a joint density function?

**Work:** I obtained
$$
\int_{0}^1\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x-\lambda y}\,dx\,dy,
$$
but I am unsure about the upper bounds. For the inner integral I obtained
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^\infty e^{-u}\,du=\frac{1}{\lambda}
$$
by $u$-substitution, and for the outer integral I obtained
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\lambda}\,dy=\frac{1}{\lambda}
$$
but I'm not sure this is quite right. Should the upper bound for my outer integral be $\infty$? But then the outer integral would diverge. Any ideas as to how to effectively calculate here? What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that we can factor the joint density as
$$
f(x,y)=e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\lambda y}; \quad (x,y\geq 0)\tag{1}.
$$
Let 
$$
I=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
$$
and note that
$$
I=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\lambda y}\, dx \,dy
=\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda y}\left[\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}\, dx \right]\,dy
=\left[\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}\, dx \right]\left[\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda y}\, dy \right]
$$
whence
$$
I=\left[\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}\, dx \right]^2=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}
$$
Thus $\lambda ^2I=1$ so $f$ must be multiplied by $\lambda ^2$ to obtain a pdf.